# return one records from database

Tags: php, oop, return, records

Thanks for answer. Now it's work, but I have next problem.
I remade a method to display records from the database:

```
 public $id, $nazwa, $quantity, $data, $godzina, $sn, $added, $kategoria, $numrows;

    public function magazyn() {
        $resultmag = $this->magazyn = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `id`");
        $resultmag = $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
        $resultmag = $this->magazyn->execute();
        $resultmag = $this->magazyn->get_result();

        if ($isset = $resultmag->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $resultmag->fetch_object()) {
            $this->id = $row->id;
            $this->nazwa = $row->nazwa;
            $this->quantity = $row->quantity;
            $this->data = $row->data;
            $this->godzina = $row->godzina;
            $this->sn = $row->sn;
            $this->added = $row->added;
            $this->kategoria = $row->kategoria;
            }
            $this->numrows = $resultmag->num_rows;
        } else {
            echo "No results database";
        }
    }

    function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->numrows;
    }

    //-------------------------------
    $mag = new Magazyn();
    $mag->magazyn();

    ?>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr><th style='text-align:center'>ID</th><th style='text-align:center'>DODAŁ</th><th style='text-align:center'>NAZWA</th><th style='text-align:center'>KATEGORIA</th><th style='text-align:center'>SERIAL</th><th style='text-align:center'>ILOŚĆ</th><th style='text-align:center'>DATA</th><th style='text-align:center'>GODZINA</th><th style='text-align:center' colspan='2'>AKCJA</th></tr>
                <?php
    $color = NULL;
    $color1 = '#99bbff';
    $color2 = '#b3ccff';

    $color == $color1 ? $color = $color2 : $color = $color1;
    echo "<tr class='active'>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $mag->id . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'><a href='panel.php?page=userpanel&user=" . $mag->added . "'>" . $mag->added . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $mag->nazwa . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'><a href='panel.php?page=category&cat=" . $mag->kategoria . "'>" . $mag->kategoria . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'><a href='panel.php?page=editserial&sn=" . $mag->sn . "'>" . $mag->sn . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $mag->quantity . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $mag->data . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $mag->godzina . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><a href='panel.php?page=magazyn&action=edit&sn=" . $mag->sn . "&nazwa=" . $mag->nazwa . "&kategoria=" . $mag->kategoria . "&id=" . $mag->id . "'</a><button  class='btn btn-default'>Edytuj</button></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><a href='panel.php?page=magazyn&action=delete&sn=" . $mag->sn . "'</a><button  class='btn btn-default'>Usuń</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

The problem is that it displays **ONLY ONE RECORD** from the database.
When I add to while echo:

```
while ($row = $resultmag->fetch_array()) {
    echo $this->id = $row['id'];
    echo $this->nazwa = $row['nazwa'];
    echo $this->quantity = $row['quantity'];
    echo $this->data = $row['data'];
    echo $this->godzina = $row['godzina'];
    echo $this->sn = $row['sn'];
    echo $this->added = $row['added'];
    echo $this->kategoria = $row['kategoria'];
}
```

Displays all of the records but by:

```
$mag->magazyn();
```

[image]

Comment: So... What's the question? How many records should it display?

Comment: you overwrite your variables in the loop, you should probably be making a multidimensional array of the output

Comment: the question is: How do I return records in the table(<table>first_record second_reord ...</table>) ?? Should display 2 records in the blue table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dagon's comment above says, add your values to a multidimensional array. Instead of

```
public $id, $nazwa, $quantity, $data, $godzina, $sn, $added, $kategoria, $numrows;
```

Just do

```
public $records = array();
public $numrows;
```

Then you are going to append all of the records to this array:

```
public function magazyn() {
    $resultmag = $this->magazyn = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `id`");
    $resultmag = $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
    $resultmag = $this->magazyn->execute();
    $resultmag = $this->magazyn->get_result();

    if ($isset = $resultmag->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $resultmag->fetch_object()) {
        $record['id'] = $row->id;
        $record['nazwa'] = $row->nazwa;
         // etc... Add all like above

        $this->records[] = $record;
        }
        $this->numrows = $resultmag->num_rows;
    } else {
        echo "No results database";
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML you loop over `$mag->records`:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <?php foreach ($mag->records as $record) : ?>
        <tr><th style='text-align:center'>ID</th><th style='text-align:center'>DODAŁ</th><th style='text-align:center'>NAZWA</th><th style='text-align:center'>KATEGORIA</th><th style='text-align:center'>SERIAL</th><th style='text-align:center'>ILOŚĆ</th><th style='text-align:center'>DATA</th><th style='text-align:center'>GODZINA</th><th style='text-align:center' colspan='2'>AKCJA</th></tr>
        <?php
        $color = NULL;
        $color1 = '#99bbff';
        $color2 = '#b3ccff';

        $color == $color1 ? $color = $color2 : $color = $color1;
        echo "<tr class='active'>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'><a href='panel.php?page=userpanel&user=" . $record['added'] . "'>" . $record['added'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $record['nazwa'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'><a href='panel.php?page=category&cat=" . $record['kategoria'] . "'>" . $record['kategoria'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'><a href='panel.php?page=editserial&sn=" . $record['sn'] . "'>" . $record['sn'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $record['quantity'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $record['data'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' style='background-color:" . $color . ";'>" . $record['godzina'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><a href='panel.php?page=magazyn&action=edit&sn=" . $record['sn'] . "&nazwa=" . $record['nazwa'] . "&kategoria=" . $record['kategoria'] . "&id=" . $record['id'] . "'</a><button  class='btn btn-default'>Edytuj</button></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><a href='panel.php?page=magazyn&action=delete&sn=" . $record['sn'] . "'</a><button  class='btn btn-default'>Usuń</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    endforeach;
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: i had that half typed up, then i gave up :-)

Comment: @Dagon I assumed you didn't want to since you didn't post anything.

Comment: By using foreach does not display table. Return a blank page

Comment: @major697 What does `echo count($mag->records); var_dump($mag->numrows);` output?

Comment: @Mike Return 6int(6)

Comment: I think it should be:     `while ($row = $resultmag->fetch_object()) {
    $this->record['id'] = $row->id;
    $this->record['nazwa'] = $row->nazwa;
    $this->record['added'] = $row->added;
    $this->record['kategoria'] = $row->kategoria;
    $this->record['sn'] = $row->sn;
    $this->record['quantity'] = $row->quantity;
    $this->record['data'] = $row->data;
    $this->record['godzina'] = $row->godzina;
    $this->records[] = $this->record;

   }`

Comment: @major697 Yes, you had to fill in some of the blanks. That's why I had the comment `// etc... Add all like above`.

Comment: @Mike Not completely. Displayed for each record a separate column title

Comment: @major697 Glad I could help. Feel free to accept this answer if you wish.